# Solving an equation by Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Consider the following equation:

$$ y^{\prime\prime}(x) +x = \int _0 ^x (x-u)y(u)du \qquad y(0)=0 \quad  y^{\prime}(0)=1$$

I solved it by Laplace transform and got $-\sinh x$ as a solution. It is easily to check that it satisfy the equation, but $y^{\prime}(0)=-1$. Why?

Comment: Are you sure your integral is set up correctly? It's strange.

Comment: I didn,t compute the integral. I took Laplace transform from the both sides and it is equal for $-\sinh x$.

Comment: But $x$ is the upper bound? And $x$ is in the integrand?

Comment: The integral can be written as convolution. $x * y(x)$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I got a wrong answer. The answer is $-\sin x$.

Comment: I have tested $-\text{sinh}(x)$ and it is a solution.

Comment: The correct answer is $y(x)=\sin x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first solve it without the use of Laplace transforms. Differentiating twice, using the product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus, we find that $y$ should satisfy
$$
y''''(x)=y(x),\quad y(0)=0,\quad y'(0)=1,\quad y''(0)=0,\quad y'''(0)=-1.
$$
This differential equation has the solution $y(x)=\sin x$ only.

With $Y(s)=(\mathcal{L}y)(s)$, I get, using the Laplace transform (and the general rules for derivatives and convolutions), that
$$
s^2 Y-1+\frac{1}{s^2}=\frac{1}{s^2}Y.
$$
Solving for $Y$ gives
$$
Y(s)=\frac{1}{1+s^2}.
$$
Thus $y(x)=\sin x$.

Comment: Yes, I had a mistake.